# What's the point in making a .jar out of everything?

Tags: java, jar

I recently ran over a bootstrap.jar. For me bootstrap is only a css / js library and I include it as such. Now following questions came up:

- What is the point of a .jar file there?
- Aren't .jar just for Java files?
- Why would I want a .jar of a JavaScript library?

I've also seen other examples of .jar files where I wouldn't expect them.  I'm most likely to see them in some artifactory.

Edit: Looking into the .jar with WinZip: It **is** the bootstrap css / js framework. inside a folder called **webjars**.

Comment: what makes you think there are no java bootstrap libraries?

Comment: Bootstrap is widely used as a term, so it's probably not the HTML bootstrap library that's in question. Tomcat for example has a `bootstrap.jar` and I'm pretty sure there's no css or javascript inside.

Comment: "It's a script that loads the browser detection which in turn loads the correct export for the browser calling it.", well that explains it then.

Comment: A jar is more or less not more than a zip archive. Try opening it with a tool like 7-zip and have a look inside to find out what is included :)
Anyhow bootstrap is a widely used term as Kayaman mentioned so be careful when interpreting by name.

Comment: @PeterSchmucki: that only describes THAT particular bootstrap. Just because one guy is called 'George', do you think it is impossible for any other family to name their newborn kid George as well? Just because two things have the same name, doesn't mean they're identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.webjars.org/

The advantages of these jars containing client-side javascript and css code include:

- Explicitly and easily manage the client-side dependencies in    JVM-based web applications
- Use JVM-based build tools (e.g. Maven, Gradle, sbt, ...) to download    your client-side dependencies
- Know which client-side dependencies you are using
- Transitive dependencies are automatically resolved and optionally    loaded via RequireJS